# After exiting RIDE application, RIDE won't open anymore because python quit working

Tags: python, windows, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Thanks for the help, I was working on ride.py, everything was working fine. Then I closed the application and it glitched for a second, and then the application closed like I wanted it to. A couple minutes later when I try to open RIDE, I get an error message which says Python has stopped working, and I have 2 options, close program or check online for a solution and close program.

Python still works on my computer, I can run it fine, so I think this is an issue with RIDE. Restarting the computer didn't help either. What can I do to get RIDE working again?

I'm on windows, and I'm running python 3.9 and I was using the beta version of RIDE which I downloaded from the RIDE github (https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) with the command `pip install -U https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/archive/master.zip`

Thanks

Comment: The problem needs to be better troubleshooted, and there is not enough information. For example, you don't mention what operating system you are using. It is also important to now how you start RIDE (and then try some other options). For this, immediate help, it is better to use Instant Conversation, like on out Robot Framework Slack.

Comment: Ok thanks I joined slack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the settings of RIDE got corrupted.
When this happens the easiest fix, is to delete the file `settings.cfg` or even the `robotframework\ride` directory, which will be recreated when RIDE is started.
When the user have some configurations that they wish to save, then it is better to make a backup, and later restore the values by directly editing `settings.cfg`.